# How can I display the year with using GANTTI (PHP GANTT class)?

Tags: php, gantt-chart

Heres the link to this script:
https://github.com/bastianallgeier/gantti

The file which generates the header info (months,days) is in 'lib/gantti.php' line 105 and the classes are on 'lib/calendar.php'...I've tried basiclly to copy and paste the month headers and modify it to display years but no luck...How can I display the year in the header section?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it...just added this line:

```
function name_year() {
return strftime('%B %Y', $this->timestamp);
}
```